# Can I avoid this borrowing issue?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

Given the following struct and function implementations:

```
struct Graph {
    edges : Vec<(usize,usize)>,
    vertices : Vec<usize>
}

impl Graph {
    pub fn new(n: usize) -> Graph {
        let mut vertices : Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
        for i in 0..n {
            vertices.push(i);
        }
        Graph {edges: Vec::new(), vertices}
    }

    pub fn get_edges(&self) -> &Vec<(usize,usize)> {
        &self.edges
    }
}
```

I try to run the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut g = Graph::new(10);

    for e in g.get_edges() {   // immutable borrow
        g.vertices[e.0] = e.1; // mutable borrow
    }
}
```

Then it complains that I have overlapping borrows.

Which makes sense, because probably `g.get_edges()` makes a borrow of the struct `g`, which overlaps with the other borrow. But in theory it would suffice if it borrows `g.edges` instead.

Which also works if I substitute it accordingly:

```
fn main() {
    let mut g = Graph::new(10);

    for e in g.edges {         // immutable borrow of g.edges?
        g.vertices[e.0] = e.1; // mutable borrow of v.vertices
    }
}
```

In this case the substitution would be no problem, but in some use cases `g.get_edges()` could perform some important background operations.

So whats the workaround around this, such that I can perform a method on some struct that returns some reference to a field (or multiple fields of it), and still perform mutable operations on different fields?

Comment: The answer lies in the understanding of references and borrowing.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references

At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references.

Comment: When accessing fields directly the borrow checker can perform so-called [split borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html) where only part of a struct is borrowed. It's a pretty limited feature: it can't handle arrays, nor does it work across method boundaries. There's been [talk](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/11/01/after-nll-interprocedural-conflicts/) about how to improve it, but it's an open problem with no clear solution on the horizon.